# Check if value in list ignoring the last few chars

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of files (some ends with _HHMMss.*** where *** is the extension).

I want to check if a specific file exist in the list ignoring the "_HHMMss", means:
if I have a list:

```
A_Log_YYYY_MM_DD_121122.csv
B_Log_YYYY_MM_DD_112211.csv
C_Log_YYYY_MM_DD_333333.csv
D_Log_YYYY_MM_DD_555555.csv
E_Log_YYYY_MM_DD_777765.csv
```

check if "A_Log_YYYY_MM_DD.csv" exist, the answer in this case is TRUE
Is there a fast way to do that?

Comment: By fast do you mean fast being developed or fast working ?

Comment: I mean without need to use loops and if .....  I'll use the .Any with Regex. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = new List<string> { .... }; // add your strings here

Regex reg = new Regex("[A-Z]_Log_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{6}.csv");
bool matches = list.Any(x => reg.IsMatch(x));
```

The linq query (`.Any(...)`) stops when the first matching element is found.